# Need help making an expanding shape

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a heart that keeps expanding from the center like [THIS](http://c.editingmyspace.com/files/en/hearts/heart_134.gif).

[Here's JSFiddle of the css heart.](http://jsfiddle.net/xffLZ/)

```
<div id="heart"></div>
```

How can I make this pulsing and expanding like the gif?

Comment: Are you using jQuery or another library or do you need this to be pure JS?

Comment: center it in a div, increase the width and height, and repeat

Comment: Why not just add the gif as an <img />?

Comment: +DrydenLong Anything is fine. 
+Ibu What about the animation?
+Dude Just looking for something cleaner/neater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you might be better off using an image rather than a css shape. Since the shape's borders are not fluid, you'll have a hard time expanding and shrinking the shape to create the pulsating effect. If you use an image, all you need to do is animate the size of the container `div` and you're good to go.

Doing this once is easy, but since I'm assuming you want it to pulsate constantly, we'll need to do the animating in a loop. Using jQuery, something like this will work well:

**jQuery**

```
function animatethis(targetElement, speed) {
    $(targetElement).animate({ width: "+=100px"},
    {
        duration: speed,
        complete: function ()
        {
            targetElement.animate({ width: "-=100px" },
            {
                duration: speed,
                complete: function ()
                {
                    animatethis(targetElement, speed);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};

animatethis($('#heart'), 2000);
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="..." id="heart" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#heart {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
}
```

And here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xffLZ/2/

To change the size, you need to adjust the two `width` values in the jQuery and in order to change the speed at which it pulsates, change the number value in `animatethis($('#heart'), 2000);`

**UPDATE**

Ok, so I kind of have an updated answer for you... I've written a script using jQuery and jQueryUI that will pulsate some heart images like in the gif example you provided. Here is an updated fiddle with what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/t9mZZ/3/

Note that this uses both jQuery and jQueryUI, so you'll be including two libraries and to be honest, a gif might be a lighter way to go. But, if you're hell-bent on making it happen without a gif, this should work.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="heart1" src="..." />
    <img id="heart2" src="..." />
<div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img{
    width:250px;
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    left: -75px;
    top: -50px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
function animatethis(target1, target2) {
    $(target1).show('scale', function () {
        $(target1).css('z-index','0');
        $(target2).css('z-index','1');
        $(target2).show('scale', function () {
            $(target1).css('z-index','1');
            $(target2).css('z-index','0');
            animatethis(target1, target2);
        });
    });
            };

animatethis($('#heart1'), $('#heart2'));
```

Comment: nice man. but he wanted to pulse the heart from center.

Comment: @learning Ah, I missed that. I'll update my code now. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to have many hearts pulsating on each other like the gif?

Comment: @user3147178 At this point, you might be better off just using the gif itself rather than trying to animate this. I misread your question so my answer isn't what you want exactly... The easiest and simplest way would be to use the gif itself.

Comment: @user3147178 I've updated my answer with a new option for you, check out the new fiddle and see if that will work for you.

Comment: @user3147178 Sweet, glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `css3`

A long time back I have seen this type of `animation`. so thought to share

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MdQ6C/)